# Get rid of multiple html tags in python using SQL query as data source

Tags: python, html, sql, excel, data-cleaning

I have a SQL query being loaded in Python and a column in the data has multiple html tags in each record. Within the tags is description data that I need. How does one remove the html tags and keep the text so then be able to export the cleaned data to Excel?

Comment: This is far too broad/vague. See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

## Note

You haven't provided any context or an example of what your data looks like.

Thus, my answer will be what I imagine an average problem of parsing HTML to be, and in worst case, it might be useless.

In the future questions, please provide a minimal example of what is your actual problem, what you tried, and what data you have, and also what it needs to be turned into.

---

## Answer

To parse something simple like

```
<html>
    <p>Hello <b>world</b></p>
</html>
```

You can use [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html):

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class Values(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data = {}
        self.current_tag = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.current_tag = tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.current_tag = None

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.data[self.current_tag] = data

parser = Values()
parser.feed('<html><p>Hello <b>world</b></p></html>')

print(parser.data)
```

From your question, I'm assuming that you do not have identical tags duplicated anywhere in individual entries, and this kind of parsing is enough to produce this:

```
{'p': 'Hello ', 'b': 'world'}
```

You now know that you found `Hello` in a `paragraph`, and `world` was `bold`.

The resulting dictionary allows you to easily access `parser.data['b']`/`.data['p']` to access relevant data and do whatever you feel like.

It would be more foolproof if you instead had a list behind every tag

```
{ 'p': ['Hello '], 'b': ['world'] }
```

but I excluded that for simplicity.

If I instead kept a list of tags, and I added a new tag to said list and removed the most recently added tag from the list on every `handle_starttag` and `handle_endtag`, I could then use `'.'.join(self.current_tags)` as a dictionary key.

This would result in a dictionary like this:

```
{ 'html.p': 'Hello ', 'html.p.b': 'world' }
```

For more sophisticated inputs, you would implement whatever logic is necessary to differentiate between the data, same can be said for the resulting data structure, it all depends on what you actually need.

Alternatively, you can use a library that does the most heavy lifting for you, one I could recommend is [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand how the parser works and how beautiful soup works but every resource I encounter only shows it for strings. I am trying to read in a query from SQL server and from there change the records that have html code in them and then export the edited query to an Excel file. Do you know how this could be done?